# RubyGem version error:rails(2.2.2 not = 2.3.11) netbeans?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I have three rails version installed on my system.
2.2.2,
2.3.9,
2.3.11

My other applications are running fine with rails 2.2.2 and 2.3.9.

I have create new application with rails 2.3.11 after that netbeans returning this error 
Rake aborted!
RubyGem version error:rails(2.2.2 not = 2.3.11)

Gem list from command prompt shows.

rails (2.3.11, 2.3.9, 2.2.2)

Netbeans Rubygems shows only rails 2.2.2 and 2.3.9.

I think there is some problem with Gem Path.

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed

Gem Home:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8

Gem Path:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8

in netbeans.

It worked for me.